# What is going on here? Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In this code below z fails with a compiler error 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'. Why is the definition of type Y different than Z?

```
type X = string | undefined
type Y<T> = T extends undefined ? string : never
type Z =  X extends undefined ? string : never

const x : X = "x"
const x2 : X = undefined

const y : Y<string | undefined> = "y"
const y2 : Y<X> = "y"

const z : Z = "z" // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Note: This also fails with distributive syntax `type Z =  [X] extends [undefined] ? string : never`

[tsplayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAGlC8UDOwBOBLAdgcygHygFdMATCAMywhIChRIoBNAHgBUA+BKVqCAD2ARSSIqQpUSUAPzI0WXAC4omCADcIqOuGgAtLrF4ChJEcTKUVkmSgw4oSles00AxgHtMKKH3sHEAIj5-Vw8vPgAmXzhEM3FLGhDPYCgQXxYbeXxRcwlOAJBg9ySUyKUWGDyofwKEoq8AL189APr-IA)

In a more complicated example below, both foo and bar fail with the same error 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'

```
type Example = {
  foo?: string,
  bar?: string
}

type Example_foo = Example["foo"] // string | undefined

type ExampleMap<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: T[P] extends undefined ? string : never
}

const v : ExampleMap<Example> = {
  foo: "biz",
  bar: "baz"
} // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

Comment: `X` is not a generic type parameter, it's just a type.  So `X extends undefined ? string : never` is not a distributive conditional type, it's just a conditional type.  `X` is not split into union pieces, so the check is `(string | undefined) extends undefined` which is false.  See the linked q/a for more informatoin.